# Can I get an Exit Visa?

Tags: visas, canada, pakistani-citizens

I am Pakistani citizen and have valid Canadian visa till August 2014. I want to go back from Canada to Pakistan and want to spend three weeks in London to visit my daughter and have confirmed ticket to go back to Pakistan. Can I get exit visa?

Comment: Exit from where?

Comment: It's not clear where you want an exit visa for and why. Please add those details and then flag this question for reopening.

Comment: I'm fairly sure he means exit from Heathrow airport...?

Comment: You don't need any kind of via to exit the UK. You may need a visa to ENTER the UK.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Neither Canada nor Pakistan issue exit visas.  Therefore, you do not need one and cannot get one.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_%28document%29#Exit_visas), exit visas exist in: Saudi Arabia, Qatar, Nepal, Uzbekistan, Cuba, North Korea.  You only need a visa to enter Canada.

Comment: @DJClayworth Good point, I've clarified the answer.